# Converting Between HubSpot Unix Timestamp and SQL DateTime

Tags: sql, t-sql, unix-timestamp

I am getting and posting data between HubSpot and my database.

HubSpot hold DateTime as UNIX Milliseconds and I am having trouble getting the same value when converting too and from.

(I want to store it as DateTime in my database which is why I am converting between them)

Starting value from HubSpot: 1531316462651

```
--FROM UNIX Starting Value TO DATETIME (This seems fine and gives me the value I would expect)
SELECT DATEADD(S, 1533046489401 / 1000, '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000')

--TO UNIX Starting Value FROM DATETIME (This doesn't give me the starting value - need help)
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(S, '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', '2018-07-31 14:14:49.000') AS BIGINT) * 1000
```

As you can see when converting to unix from datetime, it is a different value to what I started with. I might be missing something obvious from looking at this too long (SQL Blindness I call it). Hopefully a simple resolve for someone who has done this before.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: So I changed the first select statement and second statement so it reads like this:

```
--FROM UNIX TO DATETIME
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 1531316462651 % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, 1531316462651 / 1000, '19700101'))

--TO UNIX FROM DATETIME
SELECT (CAST(DATEDIFF(day, '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', '2018-07-11 13:41:02.650') AS BIGINT) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
DATEDIFF(millisecond, CAST('2018-07-11 13:41:02.650' as DATE), '2018-07-11 13:41:02.650') 
   )
```

Both return ALMOST the same value (1 Millisecond out) and I believe that is because SQL datetime rounds milliseconds in 3. So my original value 651 gets rounded to 650 when going to a datetime. I don't know how I can resolve this in SQL if anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has recognized this problem and created a function to solve it, [`DATEDIFF_BIG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  This is available since version 2016.

Before that, you need to do more complex manipulations.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT (CAST(DATEDIFF(day, '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', '2018-07-31 14:14:49.000') AS BIGINT) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
        DATEDIFF(millisecond, CAST('2018-07-31 14:14:49.000' as DATE), '2018-07-31 14:14:49.000') 
       )
```

That is, extract the days, multiply, and then extract the milliseconds from today.  A day has 86,400,400 milliseconds, so this easily fits in an integer.

To get your original value, you need milliseconds in your date/time:

```
SELECT (CAST(DATEDIFF(day, '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', '2018-07-31 14:14:49.000') AS BIGINT) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
        DATEDIFF(millisecond, CAST('2018-07-31 14:14:49.401' as DATE), '2018-07-31 14:14:49.401') 
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, the value returned by your SQL is the same as mine being 1533046489000. The value I started with is 1531316462651 which is what I am trying to get. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Toby . . . The difference is milliseconds.  You don't have milliseconds in the time constant, so they are being returned as 0.